# How to configure an USB DDR dance pad on linux?

Tags: linux, game-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure an usb ddr dance pad for Stepmania on linux ???](https://superuser.com/questions/266990/how-to-configure-an-usb-ddr-dance-pad-for-stepmania-on-linux)

I have Stepmania running and my official Dance Dance Revolution dance pad from DDR Universe 2, but I can't get the former to work with the latter.

lsusb says:

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12ab:0004 Honey Bee Electronic International Ltd.

Comment: Please don't cross-post / multiple-post the same question over multiple sites ( [1](http://superuser.com/questions/266990/how-to-configure-an-usb-ddr-dance-pad-for-stepmania-on-linux-closed), [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33676/how-to-configure-an-usb-ddr-dance-pad-for-stepmania), [3](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19567/how-to-configure-an-usb-ddr-dance-pad-for-stepmania) )